# Android L Preview upgrade

Tags: updates, rom-flashing

I was about to flash the phome with the command prompt, but an error came up saying that the device was locked. Does this mean is has to be rooted? If I root it and upgrade it will it be unrooted again because I don't want to loose my warranty.

Comment: What phone? And are you installing an official factory image or a custom ROM?

Comment: The nexus 5. I'm installing the android l developers preview

Comment: I'd expect that to work even with a locked bootloader, since it's an official image, but I haven't tried it so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: unfortunately it does not

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your bootloader is locked, which is different from rooting.  With a locked bootloader, you can only flash official signed factory images; with it unlocked, you can flash anything to any partition.

If you're following [Google's directions for installing factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#instructions), you'll see that one of the steps is to run a `fastboot oem unlock` command.  This unlocks the phone's bootloader.  **It also erases all your data**.  (But installing the L Preview system image will do that anyway.)

Comment: so it does not root the phone. Thanks bud unfortunately I cannot vote you up because I'm still new and have no reputation points :(

Comment: It doesn't root the phone, but it does void your warranty — or at least, it displays a message saying that it voids your warranty.  (But again, installing the L Preview system image will do that anyway.)  And it's possible to re-lock and flash back to a supported factory image later, leaving no trace that it's ever been unlocked.